# MVC2 JSON input

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a problem with a simple VS2010 .NET 4.0 MVC2 application.

My controller action looks like this:

`public JsonResult GetJson(string query)`

I access the action with jQuery like so:

`function getJson() {

    var postdata = {};

    postdata['query'] = $('#query').val();

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",

        url: '<%= Url.Action("GetJson") %>',

        data: JSON.stringify(postdata),

        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        dataType: "json",

        success: function (msg) {`

The action is executed upon the jQuery XHR request, but no matter what the "query" value is ALWAYS null.  I can view the POST request/response in Firebug, and it shows the proper JSON string being sent to the action.

What could the problem be?  It just seems like MVC is not parsing/deserializing the JSON input at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this as it should work for you:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<%= Url.Action("GetJson") %>',
    data: {query: $('#query').val()},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
    }
});
```